# c# cannot convert system.collections.generic.icollection<kmsentities.PMRUnitTypes> to KMSEntities.PMRUnitTypes

Tags: c#

I was troubleshooting one of our pages and I found a feachloop that had nested foreach loops in it and instead of nesting them I was going to multithread the foreach loops and break them out individually

```
List<int> buildings = new List<int>();
            List<int> wings = new List<int>();
            List<int> complexes = new List<int>();
            List<int> unittypes = new List<int>();
            int floors = 0;
            int unitcnt = 0;
            ICollection<PMRUnitTypes> units = new List<PMRUnitTypes>();
            List<PMRProjectConfig> UnityTypesObj = new List<PMRProjectConfig>();


            //for each config in the project, get the summay

            foreach (var c in prj.Configs)
            {
                //add the buildings
                if (c.PB_ID.HasValue && buildings.FirstOrDefault(b => b == c.PB_ID.Value) <= 0)
                    buildings.Add(c.PB_ID.Value);

                //add the complexs
                if (c.PC_ID.HasValue && complexes.FirstOrDefault(co => co == c.PC_ID.Value) <= 0)
                    complexes.Add(c.PC_ID.Value);

                //add the wings
                if (c.PW_ID.HasValue && wings.FirstOrDefault(w => w == c.PW_ID.Value) <= 0)
                    wings.Add(c.PW_ID.Value);

                //add the floors
                if (c.Floor_ID.HasValue)
                    floors++;

                UnityTypesObj.Add(c.UnitTypes);

                //add the unit type codes
                foreach (var ut in c.UnitTypes)
                {
                    if (unittypes.FirstOrDefault(utc => utc == ut.PUTC_ID) <= 0)
                        unittypes.Add(ut.PUTC_ID);
                }

                //get the units
                var dscnt = DataServiceLocator.RunStoreProcedureReturnDS("GetPMRUnitsCountFromConfig", 200, new SqlParameter[]{
                    new SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@PPC_ID", Value= c.PPC_ID}
                });

                foreach (DataRow r in dscnt.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    unitcnt += int.Parse(r["unitCount"].ToString());
                }
            };
```

here is my code but on the second foreach loop instead of doing that I was trying to add it to list then loop through it after this initial one is done but I am getting the error above with ICollection. I found out that PMRUnittypes is a ICollection of the config but is there any possible way to do this or write this better which would speed up the code?

the error is on   `UnityTypesObj.Add(c.UnitTypes);` and proj.configs come from the database    `var cust =`DataServiceLocator.GetCustomer_DAO().GetCustomerByID(customerID, Context);

Comment: If the data size per PPC_ID in the call against the db isn't that big, consider fetching all data from db once, before the loop, then filter the dataset from db in memory in the loop.

Comment: It always helps to tell us which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Somewhere here, in this code, you trying to stick `collection<a>` in to `a`. The error tells you that. Posting definitions, error lines, etc would help. As is, this is not clear

Comment: unittypesobj.add(c.unittypes); is throwing the error

Comment: that comes from getting the prj data from the db   var prj = DataServiceLocator.GetPMR_Project_DAO().GetPMRprojectById(id, Context);

Comment: `UnityTypesObj.AddRange(c.UnitTypes);`

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted can I mark as the answer for you?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just a small advice: you can improve the checks `buildings.FirstOrDefault(b => b == c.PB_ID.Value) <= 0` with `buildings.Any(b => b == c.PB_ID.Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `c.UnitTypes` is a collection, you need to use AddRange instead:

```
UnityTypesObj.AddRange(c.UnitTypes);
```